# Change a group of data in a dataset to a different entry

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following code for my Redundancy Analysis:
How to use a dataset to extract specific columns from another dataset? `

Comment: "change every piece of data starting with "L" to a specific colour" -> do you mean to one specific color, or each unique value to its **own"" specific color?

Comment: Just to one specific colour

Answer (score 0):

1.Create minimal reproducible example:

```
col.pred <- c("L0041" , "L0042", "L0078", "L0079", "#1f78b4")
```

2.Solution using `gsub`:

Specify the color to use:

```
the_one_specific_color <- "#f1eef5"
```

Use `gsub` to replace the matched strings:

```
col.pred_fixed <- gsub("^L\\d+", the_one_specific_color,   col.pred)

col.pred_fixed
```

Returns:

```
[1] "#f1eef5" "#f1eef5" "#f1eef5" "#f1eef5" "#1f78b4"
```

Explanation:

The line

```
gsub("^L\\d+", the_one_specific_color,   col.pred)
```

Replaces every entry in `col.pred` that starts with an L (`^L`) and is followed by at least one digit (`\\d+`) with `the_one_specific_color`. Depending on the values of `col.pred` a more or less strict regex is advisable!